# Selective can view content of cqwp

Tags: content-query-web-part

Is it possible to allow selective users part of a group only to watch the result from cqwp in Sharepoint 2013 on intranet homepage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can turn `audience targeting` on the list. Go back to each of the files and target them to the appropriate audience and then just use one webpart that honors the audience targeting.

You can better idea from steps mentioned in below MSDN article.

[Target list or library items to an audience](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293)

Please check the content for **Target list or library items to an audience** in above article.

Comment: Audience target I had in my mind, but the confusion is what will the CQWP would display for users who are not part of target audience. Will it show an error or customized message

Comment: If you set target audience in list or library than your CQWP will display only those items to users which are allowed. That's it.. Simple..

Comment: Did you get it working for you?

Comment: Not yet, will be testing it next week, as currently working on getting a custom CQWP to display data in Table format from multiple SPS list.

Comment: Keep me posted here. if you need help than kindly let me know. Thanks for update

Comment: Did you tried my solution?